# Unable to upload datafusion plugin json file using CDAP RESTAPI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

I am trying to upload my custom plugin to datafusion using CDAP RESTAPI reference. I followed the steps as per documentation but I still didn't find the way to add the plugin JSON file using REST API.

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" "${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/api/v3/namespaces/vega_demo/artifacts/example" -H "Artifact-Extends: system:cdap-data-pipeline[6.0.0,10.0.0-SNAPSHOT)/system:cdap-data-streams[6.0.0,10.0.0-SNAPSHOT)" --data-binary @/path/to/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar @/path/to/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.json

Artifact added successfullycurl: (6) Could not resolve host:

Plugin is loaded but the config json file is not loaded causing errors in plugin

Comment: could you share the JSON file used? Also, have you tried to upload the plugin by using the interface?

Comment: @ebeltran, Actually as per documentation, the syntax is there just to upload the JAR like --data-binary @/path/to/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.  Can you help me on syntax on how to pass the JSON file in the above CURL command.

Comment: Per the official documentation, it seems that within the curl command you don't need to specify the json file. To load the json, you use the cdap command https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/current/en/developer-manual/pipelines/plugin-management.html#H3558

Comment: @ebeltran, Then how can I upload the JSON file using REST ?.  I cannot use CDAP CLI because I am using datafusion.

Answer (score 1):

Per the command used, I suggest to verify if you are setting correctly the endpoint.

```
export INSTANCE_ID=your-instance-id
export CDAP_ENDPOINT=$(gcloud beta data-fusion instances describe \
--location=us-central1 \
--format="value(apiEndpoint)" \
${INSTANCE_ID})
```

Per the official CDAP [documentation](https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/current/en/developer-manual/pipelines/plugin-management.html#H3888), it seems that the endpoint should not include the part **api** before **v3**.

Also, if your instance belongs to [Basic edition](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/reference/cdap-reference#create_a_pipeline), the namespace is **default**; otherwise, when using Enterpise edition you can create the namespace.

When using the curl method, it seems you need to add the config information within the [headers](https://docs.cask.co/cdap/3.6.0/en/developers-manual/building-blocks/plugins.html) due this method doesn't include the json load

On the other hand, if you are having issues to use curl, I would suggest to use the UI.

Taking this [example](http://%7B%20%20%20%22parents%22:%20[%20%22cdap-data-pipeline[6.1.1,6.1.1]%22%20],%20%20%20%22plugins%22:%20[%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%20:%20%22mysql%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20:%20%22jdbc%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22className%22%20:%20%22com.mysql.jdbc.Driver%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22description%22%20:%20%22Plugin%20for%20MySQL%20JDBC%20driver%22%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%20:%20%22postgresql%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20:%20%22jdbc%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22className%22%20:%20%22org.postgresql.Driver%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22description%22%20:%20%22Plugin%20for%20PostgreSQL%20JDBC%20driver%22%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20]) to upload the plugin **mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar** to Data fusion with curl, the configuration file should be like:

```
{
  "parents": [ "system:cdap-data-pipeline[6.1.1,6.1.1]", "system:cdap-data-streams[6.1.1,6.1.1]" ],
  "plugins": [
    {
      "name": "mysql",
      "type": "jdbc",
      "className": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    }
  ]
}
```

due using curl you can only upload the jar **file**, to include the information from the configuration file, you should use the HTTP Headers to include this information as this:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
"${CDAP_ENDPOINT}/v3/namespaces/default/artifacts/example" \
-H 'Artifact-Plugins: [ { "name": "mysql", "type": "jdbc", "className": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" } ]' \
-H "Artifact-Version: 5.1.35" \
-H "Artifact-Extends: system:cdap-data-pipeline[6.1.1, 6.1.1]/system:cdap-data-streams[6.1.1, 6.1.1]" \
--data-binary @mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar
```

Comment: I followed the above steps only before posting this question. I even added the headers to the CURL and still facing the same error. Could you please provide an working example of CURL with JAR and JSON?

Comment: Just to clear things out, this has to be done in two steps. 1. Upload artifact (jar). 2. Once the artifact is uploaded, you can then use the artifact properties endpoint to update the properties of the artifact (json file).

1. API for uploading artifact (https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/6.1.1/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/artifact.html#H2312)
2. API for updating properties of an artifact (https://docs.cdap.io/cdap/6.1.1/en/reference-manual/http-restful-api/artifact.html#set-artifact-properties)